# How can I catch an event of a new postgreSQL record with golang

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, notifications, pg

I have a script that connects to DB and can get data from it
Can I somehow make it to notify me, when any new record is added to the DB table

Comment: [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-notify.html) and [friends](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/libpq-notify.html) might be of interest. AFAIK you'd need to set up insert-triggers on the tables you want to watch and I'm not sure how well any of this works with Go's PostgreSQL interface.

Comment: Take a look at Postgresql Listen/Notify feature. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-listen.html
You can create a listener which sends a NOTIFY-Message to a channel.
You can listen on that channel in golang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved this using sql triggers and `go-pg` library:

1. Create sql function called `insert_test_func`, that on `INSERT` do:

   ```
   PERFORM pg_notify('mychan', 'Message');
   ```
2. Create trigger, that executes func:

   ```
   create trigger check_insert 
   before insert or update on *my_table_name*
   for each row 
   execute procedure insert_test_func();
   ```
3. Execute this trigger
4. With `github.com/go-pg/pg`, connect to the DB and with `pg.Listen()` listening to the channel for the `'Message'`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `LISTEN/NOTIFY` features of Postgresql.

With `"github.com/lib/pq"`, you can easily fetch notify-events and react to new database-events.

Here is an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/hOsU89oC6fS) of the go implementation.